# Random variable independence

Tags: probability

Consider two discrete binary random variables A and B. If $P(A=1,B=0) = P(A=1)P(B=0)$, can we conclusively say that A and B are independent?

My response is we cannot conclusively say they are independent because the $P(AB) = P(A)P(B)$ should hold for all possible values of A and B.

Comment: Use the fact that they are binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this special case, the single equation $P(A=1, B=0)=P(A=1)P(B=0)$ actually implies all the other equations.

For instance,
\begin{align}
P(A=0, B=0)
&= P(B=0) - P(A=1, B=0)
\\
&= P(B=0) - P(A=1) P(B=0)
\\
&= (1 - P(A=1))P(B=0)
\\
&= P(A=0)P(B=0).
\end{align}